# IIS7 permit access only to local network

Tags: windows, iis-7

I am having a problem with the IIS 7 on a Win 2008 server. I only want to have access to it inside my network and denied access from anyone outside the network. I had created a rule to permit access to the group of computers with the IP: 192.168.0.1 (255.255.255.0). In the IIS6 this was enougth to prevent access of any IP that don't belong to the network. Any idea of how can I block these access? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use IP Seсurity (IP Address and Domain restrictions role for IIS7) - it allows you to block a list of IP addresses.

Look at [IP Security](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity)

Answer (score 1):

The same rule should work in IIS7, you may need to install the component for IP Filtering though via the Role Manager.

In addition to the built-in request filtering, there is an addon for dynamic filtering -- http://www.iis.net/download/DynamicIPRestrictions

Comment: Should I install this component as I had installed the IIS7 in the win2008, or I had to download anything? Thanks!

Comment: IIRC it is not an additional download, but a checkbox you need to check during the edit server roles wizard.

Answer (score 0):

The rule should be: 192.168.0.0 (255.255.255.0)
to allow all clients on the 192.168.0.x network access.

First edit the configuration to deny all, then add this rule